# Best practices for SQL transactions in Java

Tags: java, mysql, transactions

For a particular problem, I'm looking to use Database transactions.
I have never done that in past. My question is if I could use plain JDBC for that or Java provides something nicer (framework..) to implement this?
Is there any design pattern I could look at?

Thanks

Comment: 30 seconds of Googling would have revealed this: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/

Comment: You can look for Hibernate as an alternative of JDBC.

Comment: @Pramod If he starts with connecting to database, I strongly recommend to understand the JDBC first as the direct layer between Java and database. Moreover Hibernate is not a good example of ORM for beginners due its complexity and long configuration files.

Comment: Thanks guys, I know about JDBC and SQL queries and  I know how to use Transactions in SQL. I'm looking for a suggestion about the best practices here.
Any design patterns/ any frameworks? any orchestrations?

Comment: Hibernate is not an alternative for JDBC.  It's built on top of JDBC and adds a great deal of complexity.  All Java SQL solutions use JDBC.  I would recommend Spring JdbcTemplate, because it removes so much of the boilerplate without adding too much complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer on the internet, but i will summarize it for you. In the case of transactions you basically have to follow a few steps:

In the try block:

- you have to set auto commit to false,
- do your sql queries and stuff (PreparedStatement outperforms the simple Statement),
- make sure you commit.

In the catch block:

- rollback the database changes (in case of an error).

In the finally block:

- check if not null and close all the PreparedStatements,
- check if not null and close the database connection.

Here is a sample:

```
try{
    connection = getDatabaseConnection();
    //set connection auto commit to false
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    PreparedStatement sqlPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("sql statement here");
    //set all the values in the prepared statement
    sqlPreparedStatement.setString(1,"string");
    sqlPreparedStatement.setString(2,"anotherstring");

    sqlPreparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    PreparedStatement secondSqlStatement = connection.prepareStatement("sql statement here");
    //set all the values in the prepared statement
    secondSqlStatement.setString(1,"whatever");
    secondSqlStatement.setString(2,"sample");

    secondSqlStatement.executeUpdate();

    //commit the changes
    connection.commit();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();//or whatever
    //rollback the changes
    connection.rollback();   
} finally {
    //close the PreparedStatement and the connection if not null
    if (sqlPreparedStatement != null) {
        sqlPreparedStatement.close();
    }
    if (secondSqlStatement != null) {
        secondSqlStatement.close();
    }
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
    }
}
```